How are all Lebesgue-integrable functions Henstock-Kurzweil integrable?
When I look at the characteristic function for the irrationals (1 for irrationals, 0 for rationals), which is known to be Lebesgue-integrable, I cannot see how it can be Henstock-Kurzweil integrable.
For every gauge, I can still choose the tags (function evaluation points) such that either all are rational or all or irrational, thus the Riemann sum can still be both 0 or 1, no matter how fine of a partition is enforced by the gauge.
What am I missing?

Did you try google? When I googled Henstock-Kurzweil + integral+ "Dirichlet function" the snippet views suggest that that your question is answered in most of them. Indeed, the 3rd hit was the Wikipedia entry for Henstock–Kurzweil integral, after which a search-in-page for "Dirchlet" led me to the Utility section where exactly what you are asking is discussed.

The Wikipedia entry does this - it uses the fact that the rationals have measure zero to show that the gauge can be set up in such a way that the intervals containing the rational evaluation points selected can cover only a small part of the interval. So most of the interval requires irrational evaluation points.

I read the article on Wikipedia. The way the HZ-integral is defined there (We now define a number I to be the Henstock–Kurzweil integral of f if for every ε > 0 there exists a gauge δ such that whenever P is δ-fine ...) I read as the gauge is defined first, then the interval partioning and evaluation points can be arbitrarily selected (under the contraint of the gauge). The way you argue would require that the evaluation points are selected first, then the gauge has to be chosen depending on the evaluation points.

Ah, I think I got it now. As the rationals are countable, the gauge values for the rationals can be choosen such that the sum (infinite series) over all rationals in the interval is less than ε/2, thus the sum of the lengths of the intervals containing rational evaluation points is less than ε.
